# System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'dev.xyz.com'

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

My WCF service is .Net 3.5 , my web application aspx is also .Net 3.5. We recently moved from Windows server 2010 to Server 2016.

We are getting below error:

[image]
    ………………………………………………………

I searched few blogs and they suggest to add code :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

I am not sure this line will resolve the issue.

Also I do not know how to use this statement in my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error mainly indicates that there is something wrong with the trust relationship. Due to the service on the server-side is secured by a certificate, we should trust the server certificate before making a call. Meanwhile, both the server’s machine and the client’s machine will negotiate a communication over the `SSL/TLS` protocol, which is determined by the OS and the Dotnet framework version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
Trust relation could be established by the following statement.
Client-side (just add it before making a call).

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(uri));
```

Alternatively, we could install the server certificate in the Local CA.
[image]
This line code segments typically specify a `TLS/SSL` version, which is not advisable, just let OS decided on the TLS/SSL version.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Like the above statement used to trust the server certificate, we just add it on the client-side before making a call.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.